# Using Teradata macros from Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, teradata

Is it possible to use Teradata Macros directly from Entity Framework? I tried the model designer and guessed they would show up under stored procedures which they don't. Does the Teradata .Net provider support macros at all?

Or, do I have to manually write the SQL sentences to execute the macros?

Comment: The Teradata .Net provider should support macros. Not familiar with the Entity Framework and what you are trying to accomplish. I am guessing you are trying to avoid submitting EXEC <DB>.<Macro> (<parm list>); directly.